# Why Angular is not loading anything when query param is passed in the URL?

Tags: angular

I have an angular app that is integrated with Microsoft single sign on lib `azure/msal-browser` and `azure/msal-angular`

my **app-routing.module.ts** looks like the following:

```
  {
    path:'clients',
    component: ClientSearchComponent,
    data: { title: 'Client Search' },
    canActivate: [MsalGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'clients/:id',
    component: ClientDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      tab: ClientDetailsResolver,
      headerData: ClientDetailHeaderDataResolver
    },
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'demographics',
        component: ClientIdentInfoComponent,
        data: { title: 'Client Demographics' },
        resolve: { client: ClientIdentInfoResolver },
        canDeactivate: [ ClientIdentInfoGuard ],

      },
      {
        path: 'insurances',
        component: ClientInsuranceComponent,
        data: { title: 'Client Insurances' },
        resolve: { insurances: InsuranceInfoResolver },
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'demographics',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
  }
```

I have an external service where users click on a button and gets redirected to another page (not a new tab). After they put in their username and hit submit, the service then redirects them to my application with the following url:

```
mydomain.com/clients?code=zcwZmVmMDJkYjJmZmQtOGIz_PF84_0be990f3-c9a9-483d-b0ca-f87b327c76b3&state=7f1934f6-4te0-4687-ac81-47316c60efe5
```

for some reason, my application is not displaying anything, even a `console.log('whatever')` on the level of the **app.component.ts** is not showing.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('whatever'); // Not reachable

    const currentPath = this.location.path();
    // Dont perform nav if in iframe or popup, other than for front-channel logout
    this.isIframe = BrowserUtils.isInIframe() && !window.opener && currentPath.indexOf("logout") < 0; // Remove this line to use Angular Universal
    this.setLoginDisplay();

    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
      })
  }
```

if I changed the query param `code` to literally **ANTYHING** then the app works just fine and it displays the page. Unfortunately, I cannot control the param name `code` from the third-party app. It seems like my app is having a problem with the query param `code` if it was passed in the url.

The `IPublicClientApplication` logger is showing that my app is going into an infinite loop

```
Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - Event callback registered with id: f39e816c-5bc5-4fa5-8629-c440356cfdf5
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - Guard - canActivate
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - MSAL Guard activated
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectStart
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback f39e816c-5bc5-4fa5-8629-c440356cfdf5: msal:handleRedirectStart
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - BroadcastService - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress to handleRedirect
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - handleRedirectPromise called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - getAllAccounts called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - handleRedirectPromise has been called for the first time, storing the promise
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Info - handleRedirectPromise called but there is no interaction in progress, returning null.
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectEnd
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback f39e816c-5bc5-4fa5-8629-c440356cfdf5: msal:handleRedirectEnd
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - BroadcastService - msal:handleRedirectEnd results in setting inProgress to none
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - getAllAccounts called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - Guard - at least 1 account exists, can activate or load
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Info - Guard - Hash contains known code response, stopping navigation.
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - Guard - canActivate
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - MSAL Guard activated
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Info - Emitting event: msal:handleRedirectStart
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback f39e816c-5bc5-4fa5-8629-c440356cfdf5: msal:handleRedirectStart
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - BroadcastService - msal:handleRedirectStart results in setting inProgress to handleRedirect
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - handleRedirectPromise called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - getAllAccounts called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - handleRedirectPromise has been called previously, returning the result from the first call
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-browser@2.14.2 : Verbose - getAllAccounts called
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - Guard - at least 1 account exists, can activate or load
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Info - Guard - Hash contains known code response, stopping navigation.
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::2
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - Guard - canActivate
app.module.ts:122 Log Level:::::3
app.module.ts:121 Message:::::[Tue, 24 May 2022 18:05:01 GMT] :  : @azure/msal-angular@2.0.0 : Verbose - MSAL Guard activated
```

I am using popup not redirect for the auth

my **app.module.ts** looks like this

```
export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
  console.log('Message:::::' + message);
  console.log('Log Level:::::' + logLevel);
}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: '<clientId>',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tid>',
      redirectUri: '/',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11. Remove this line to use Angular Universal
    },
    system: {
      allowRedirectInIframe: true,
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
        piiLoggingEnabled: true
      }
    }
  });
}

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  const baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
  protectedResourceMap.set(baseUrl, ['<clientId>/.default']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: ['clientId/.default']
    },
    loginFailedRoute: '/unauthorized'
  };
}
```

and the providers array looks like this

```
providers: [
    CdkColumnDef,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
```

Have any of you had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using MSAL, you can set the logger to show more details to see if it's the interceptor that is causing troubles:

```
export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
  console.log(message);
}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {

  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {...your auth parms...},
    cache: {... your cache parms ...},
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
        piiLoggingEnabled: true
      }
    }
  });
}
```

This gave us more insights in what was causing issues with the routing.

Comment: I see, now .. it is creating an infinite loop for some reason

Comment: I already updated my question with the Verbose.. and yet, I still don't understand why removing the work code would actually fix the problem

Comment: It seems that you use REDIRECT. Is it possible to use POPUP login to check if that is causing the issue. We're using popup logins and those work great with dynamic routes.

Comment: I am using popup only for MSALInterceptorConfigFactory and MSALGuardConfigFactory. The interaction type is popup InteractionType.Popup

Comment: I updated my question to include app.module.ts

Comment: And removing the MSALGuard on the **clients** route stops the redirects in MSAL? There are some additional recommendations from MS when using MSAL: [link](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/docs/FAQ.md#authentication). But no definite pointers yet.

Comment: removing the msalGuard will fix the issue, but then how am I gonna protect this route?

Comment: also, there is still the param name issue, if it was named 'xyz' then the page will load and it will not go into infinite loop

Comment: after I removed the msalGuard from the path, it worked but if I tried to navigate to any other route, it will go into infinite loop

Comment: Interesting: if I use the word code in one of our routes with query parameters: it reroutes back to the Home component. seems that the word code is special...

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/4190) PR, Microsoft solved it by updating MSAL. Also see the related [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/4084). It seems to be fixed in a newer package.

Comment: hahahah.. damn it. Then it is an issue. I am gonna read through this PR .. Is there a way to implement a workaround without upgrading to the newest PR

Comment: I have "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.0", "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.14.2", and I am running Angular 11

Comment: I have updated  @azure/msal-angular to 2.3.0 and @azure/msal-browserto 2.24.0. Running Angular12. And this fixed the problem for me. Can you upgrade these packages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245027/discussion-between-charlie-v-and-ray).